# Springboot 2.7.1 error: cannot find symbol @Lazy

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to fix a circular dependency in a legacy project.

```java
    @Service
    @Slf4j
    public class FlowpathSubscriber {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pubSubTemplate")
    private PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private FlowpathBigQueryProcessor flowpathBigQueryProcessor;

    @Value("${subscription}")
    private String subscription;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private SlackNotificationService slackNotificationService;
```

I added `@Lazy` to `SlackNotificationService` as it was causing a circular dependency issue. However adding `@Lazy` causes an error during Gradle compilation:

```
error: cannot find symbol @Lazy
```

Comment: can you tell from import statements from where @Lazy is trying to import?

Comment: I'm not seeing any import statements related to @Lazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do 2 things:

1. don't forget to import `Lazy` i.e. `import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy`;
2. You need to put `@Lazy` on `SlackNotificationService` bean(component) as well.

See this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation#2-with-autowired